# How to send a template message in iMessages on iOS?

Tags: iphone, messages

I receive multiple questions a day on my iPhone and need to send the same reply to them. If my phone is on and open and I read the text, is there a way to send the same reply with out having to type it out?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Answer (score 2):

You could experiment with using the Text Replacement function in Settings > General > Keyboard. While in iMessage, type the shortcut to spool out the replacement text. It was able to hold quite a lot of text to spool, too.

[image: "Thank you for your interest in Zamboni Curliques"]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Different! I know of no way to do this internally in imessage. A workaround, which you may have already considered, is to open the notes app and leave it open to a new note page. Every time you reply to a text message just copy it and paste it in the Notes page. Now whenever you receive the same message, you can copy and paste from Notes. This is probably more work than you want for short replies but if your replies are many lines long this would help a lot.

Someone else may answer this question with a better answer but in case they don't you have an easy workaround.